# php search engine for a database with foreignkeys

Tags: php, mysql

hi all Im trying to create a php search page that will bring up a list of books from a mysql database, then when the book name is clicked bring up a a list of books that are in a relationship table with them. I'm slightly struggling with the code and was hoping someone would be able to lend a hand

-This is my search.php file

```
  <?php
    $i=0;
    $column_name = 'title'; // column to search by
    $k =$_GET['k'];
    $terms = explode(" ",$k);
    //connect before calling mysql_real_escape_string
    mysql_connect("localhost","","");
    mysql_select_db("test");
    $query ="SELECT id,title,author 
    FROM  books WHERE";
    foreach ($terms as $each){
        $i++;
        $each = '%' . $each . '%'; // add wildcard
        $each = mysql_real_escape_string($each); // prevent sql injection
        if($i==1)
            $query .= " $column_name LIKE '$each' ";
        else
            $query .= " OR $column_name LIKE '$each' ";

    }

    echo 'QUERY: ' . $query;

    $query = mysql_query($query) OR DIE(mysql_error());

//Code below is for using the relationships table assuming you have a column name id that
//references to the relationships table. Also, you should add a index on the column id.

$results = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $results .= '<li>
                <a href="book-relationships.php?id='.$row['relationshipid'].'">'.$row['title'].'  author: '.$row['author'].'</a>
              </li>';
}

$results = '<ul>' . $results . '</ul>';

echo $results;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting errors? Are you getting data that is different than what you expect? (Also, there's a `";` floating in there after the query, which would cause a syntax error.)

Comment: Syntax errors: `FROM books WHERE ";                 ";`, plus sql injection vulnerabilities... better fix those up before you try anything else.

Comment: i dont know how to code it so the link will come up and the compiler is throwing issues with the $i++(unidefined), $query .= "$keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";(undefined, and the num rows(boolean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove a "; from this line:

```
FROM books WHERE ";                 ";
```

You must declare $i

```
$i = 0;
```

To prevent sql injection you can use:

```
foreach ($terms as $each){
        $i++;
        $each = '%' . $each . '%'; // add wildcard
        $each = mysql_real_escape_string($each); // prevent sql injection
        if($i==1)
            $query .= " $keywords LIKE '$each' ";
        else
            $query .= " OR $keywords LIKE '$each' ";

    }
```

Also, ake sure the user cannot set the variable to a table that does not exist

Full Code

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    $column_name = 'title'; // column to search by
    $k =$_GET['k'];
    $terms = explode(" ",$k);
    //connect before calling mysql_real_escape_string
    mysql_connect("localhost","","");
    mysql_select_db("test");
    $query ="SELECT id,title,author 
    FROM  books WHERE";
    foreach ($terms as $each){
        $i++;
        $each = '%' . $each . '%'; // add wildcard
        $each = mysql_real_escape_string($each); // prevent sql injection
        if($i==1)
            $query .= " $column_name LIKE '$each' ";
        else
            $query .= " OR $column_name LIKE '$each' ";

    }

    echo 'QUERY: ' . $query;

    $query = mysql_query($query) OR DIE(mysql_error());

//Code below is for using the relationships table assuming you have a column name id that
//references to the relationships table. Also, you should add a index on the column id.

$results = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $results .= '<li>
                <a href="book-relationships.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'  author: '.$row['author'].'</a>
              </li>';
}

$results = '<ul>' . $ results . '</ul>';

echo $results;
```

Comment: the way i have edited has created an error on the following line

$query .= "$keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";

Comment: try the code above. and did you declare the $keywords variable?

Comment: You must connect to the database before calling mysql_real_escape_string. Copy and paste my full code.

Comment: localhost is the name of the server and there are no passwords/usernames and the database name is test

Comment: it has gotten rid of the errors but the data is not being retrieved. i'm typing the name of the book into the search and its not printing anything out. 

the name of the field is title, author I'm trying to retrieve but no luck

Comment: QUERY: SELECT title,author FROM books WHEREjarrads LIKE '%jarrads%'

Comment: It's missing a space between WHERE and jarrads. My code has a space :) and it should work fine after that.

Comment: i added the space but its still not getting anything from the db, maybe its something with the way I have set the connection up?

this is pulling results from the books table, is it possible you could point me in the right direction of where too look for when the person clicks on the the title information from the relationships table is displayed about the book?

Comment: What is the name of the tables for both the books and relationships?

Comment: Try running the new code I posted again. I will show you how to get the information from the relationships table after.

Comment: this was printed out QUERY: SELECT title,author FROM books WHERE title LIKE '%jarrads%'

Comment: Change title to the column name.

Comment: QUERY: SELECT title,author FROM books WHERE column_name LIKE '%jarrads%' Unknown column 'column_name' in 'where clause'

Comment: Instead of column_name it should be the column you are searching in... so 'title'. Check my code again, I gave you a hint on how to use the book relationships

Comment: QUERY: SELECT title , author FROM books WHERE relationshipid LIKE '%jarrads%' Unknown column 'relationshipid' in 'where clause'

Comment: WHERE [name of column that contains book title] LIKE [text to search for]

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $results .= '<li>
                <a href="book-relationships.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'  author: '.$row['author'].'</a>
              </li>'
}*wamp doesnt like this line? unexpected '}'

$results = '<ul>' . $ results . '</ul>';

Comment: QUERY: SELECT id,title,author FROM books WHERE title LIKE '%jarrads%' Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Comment: its still outputting this even when I've changed the code, the id for relationships table is relationshipid, but the foreign key in relationships is bookone and booktwo(both referencing bookid field from the books table)


QUERY: SELECT id,title,author FROM books WHERE title LIKE '%jarrads%' Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Comment: This is not a place to have a rolling debug session; update the question and or answer where appropriate.  I'm locking the comment thread now.